# Is there a simple way to invoke a function inside in an event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to invoke the function inside the event `$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () {}` in the function cc() in Code 1.

The Code 2 can do it, but I think it's too complex, is there a simple way to do it?

**Code 1**

```
function cc(){
   //How to invoke $('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () event
}    

$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () {
  var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);
  var defaultname = fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  defaultname = decodeURIComponent(defaultname);
  if (confirm('Do you want to delete the folder ' + defaultname + ' and all the sub-folders ?')) {
    location.href = "actiondeletefolder.htm?fullfilename=" + fileName + "&origurl=" + GetOrigUrl() + AdditionalURL();
  }
});
```

**Code 2**

```
function aa(){
   //Do  something
   bb();
}   

$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () {
  bb();        
});

function bb(){
  var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);
  var defaultname = fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
  defaultname = decodeURIComponent(defaultname);
  if (confirm('Do you want to delete the folder ' + defaultname + ' and all the sub-folders ?')) {
    location.href = "actiondeletefolder.htm?fullfilename=" + fileName + "&origurl=" + GetOrigUrl() + AdditionalURL();
  }
}
```

Comment: its the simplest way you have done it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('.CssDeleteFolder').click()` or synonymous `$('.CssDeleteFolder').trigger("click")` to trigger `click` event.

However, for me it seems like a bad code smell. 
If your function provides a reusable behavior, it is a much better idea to use a named function and bind it instead of triggering an event with anonymous handler.
I would recommend using second approach if this function needs to be called (or has a chance that it will need to be called) from other places. You may also want to use a non-global context (f.i., using IIFE) to not pollute global namespace.

By the way, you can do:

```
$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(bb);
```

instead of

```
$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () {
    bb();        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy and simple. I assume that you are using jquery. You can invoke click event of any element like:

```
$('.CssDeleteFolder').trigger('click'); // This will fire the click event manually.
```

You can trigger any event you have attached to  your control by using the following syntax:

```
$('YourSelector').trigger('eventName');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you asked for:

```
function cc(){
    $('.CssDeleteFolder').click();
}

$('.CssDeleteFolder').click(function () {
        var fileName = GetHiddenFilename(this);
        var defaultname = fileName.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        defaultname = decodeURIComponent(defaultname);
        if (confirm('Do you want to delete the folder ' + defaultname + ' and all the sub-folders ?')) {
            location.href = "actiondeletefolder.htm?fullfilename=" + fileName + "&origurl=" + GetOrigUrl() + AdditionalURL();
        }
});
```